# Gives an error "EXception in thread "main" java.util.InputMistmatchException....", I can't find a bug. Explain, pls

Tags: java, debugging

this is a code:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
             int times = in.nextInt();
             int sum = 0;
                 for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
                       int quantity = in.nextInt();
                       double price = in.nextDouble();
                        if(price < 50.00) {
                            sum += quantity;
                        }
                  }
                  System.out.println(sum);
              }
           }
```

and this is my input:

```
3
2 100.00
5 23.00
10 22.50
```

output SHOULD BE:

```
15
```

we sum that integers that has double near by them less than 50.00.

Comment: you have to paste her whole exception thatyou seen

Comment: I ran this program with your given input and indeed got the expected result - `15`. Is there a different input that crashes it? Or perhaps you've pasted a different version of the code than you're running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scanner class uses the current system locale to process the input. If you have a locale that does not have the dot (.) as decimal separator, the scanner will not recognize your input as a double value. You can test this by adding the line

```
in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

to your code. It will then run without exception and return your expected result. Vice versa, people with an english system locale can reproduce the exception by setting a non english locale, for example

```
in.useLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

If something wrong with your online judging system use:

```
import java.util.*;
//...
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

BTW, This post means that you missed the lesson, we experienced it on e-olimp during our lessons :P